# How to use IIS for directory browsing for dynamic files?

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-core

I need to use IIS only for directory browsing. The directory contains ASP.NET Core files and IIS automatically attempts to serve them normally.

Is there a way to force IIS to display all files as static files?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Do you want your visitors to be able to download .DLL and .cshtml files?

Comment: I don't want to download. I am playing with deployments and need to see the files frequently without the need to RDP to the server. I have restricted the application to my IP only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to let IIS serves everything as static content, you have to

1. Keep only Static Files handlers
2. enable directory browsing
3. Add mime type for every file. Without that IIS won't know how to serve unknown file type
4. Disable request filtering to download `.config` file, `bin` folder content, etc.

You will find below the corresponding web.config

> **WARNING** : big security issue. Be sure to understand the risk before applying this configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="StaticFiles" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <clear />
                </hiddenSegments>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <clear />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is working, however, my application has its own web.config. Is this possible to make IIS ignore web.config inside all subdirectories?

Comment: @SohailAhmed not really. Another way of doing it would be to write your own application that do the listing and everything. This app would not be that difficult to write and you will have full control of everything instead of relying on the basic DirectoryBrowsing module